# C# Windows Forms - Multiple Serial Port communications

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I am developing a c# Windows Forms Test application that is used to communicate using a certain protocol, with up to 3 devices connected to 3 serial ports on the test PC and does the following:

1. The user can select up to 3 serial ports and configure them
   individually. Each port is connected to a device under test.
2. Once the port selection is done, the user clicks a "Start Test" button which loads a form that presents the user with 3 tabs. Each tab has a datagrid table showing the selected tests and result of each test as it runs. Is will also have a window showing the serial messages transmitted and received.
3. Under each tab, the user clicks a button to start a particular test or range of tests for that device.
4. The user will click each tab, and start the tests for each device.

My questions are: How can I simultaneously communicate with each serial port in c# given that the protocol is the same? 
I am looking for coding snippets that shows how to setup the 3 serial ports and send/receive data, that is not blocking (will not momentarily freeze the UI).

Comment: You will have to use Threading or BackgroundWorker at least, definitely. But be careful, data racing is a major problem while doing it. There are thousands of sources on the internet explaining how to do parallel operations at the background while running the UI thread at the same time.

Comment: You can use a Background worker to start the tests, for the incoming data you can use 3 different `SerialPort`s with 3 different `DataReceived` events in which you update your datagrid